# if([aString writeToFile: @"outfile" atomically: YES])

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

For some code like

```
if([aString writeToFile: @"outfile" atomically: YES])
```

I am wondering if atomically is a parameter or a parameter name?

Comment: It's usually referred to as the parameter label, but it's actually a part of the selector name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter name would be what the variable is called. I guess you could call it a parameter but parameter is a very general term in my opinion.

I think the correct thing to say is that it's the method name, It's a part of it. Just that you can have parameters in between to kind of split it up.

And btw this is one of the things I love in objective c, the code gets so readable thanks to it :)